# position inside getview is getting changed in onCheckedChaneListener which is inside Adapter

Tags: android, listview, radio-button

I have Created a Listview with CustomAdapter which is having radio button in each row [ Single choice ] bt its resulting wrong after adapter has been setted

```
  if (arr_data.get(position).isdefaultCurrency())   holder.radio_currency.setChecked(true);
  } else {
        holder.radio_currency.setChecked(false);
    }
    holder.radio_currency.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                for (int k = 0; k < arr_data.size(); k++) {
                    if (k == position) {
                        arr_data.get(k).setIsdefaultCurrency(true);
                    } else {
                        arr_data.get(k).setIsdefaultCurrency(false);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                arr_data.get(position).setIsdefaultCurrency(false);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What happens when you run your app and how does that differ from what you want?

Comment: for position value 1   **Iscurrencydefault()** value  is true.so it is going to oncheckedchangelistener bt there the position returns 0 while checking at this condition 'if(k==position)'. thats my problem.

Comment: Can you give a **complete** code example? What class and method contains the code you gave above?

Comment: Also, be sure to give all declarations for variables used in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this more complicated than necessary. It appears that you have a list of radio buttons and you want to know which one was selected. Rather than using a list of `boolean` values, just store a single `int` with the position of the selected. Alternatively, store something more meaningful to represent the default currency, such as a character `'$'`, etc.

Comment: Issue was resolved simply by using OnClickListener instead of onCheckedChangeListener

Comment: holder.radio_currency.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int k = 0; k < arr_data.size(); k++) {
                    if (k == position) {
                        arr_data.get(k).setIsdefaultCurrency(true);
                    } else {
                        arr_data.get(k).setIsdefaultCurrency(false);
                    }
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

Comment: @MegalaMani Feel free to post your own answer. Then you can format the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

My Issue was resolved simply by Using OnClickListener instead of OnCheckedChangeListener.

```
  holder.radio_currency.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int k = 0; k < arr_data.size(); k++) {
                if (k == position) {
                    arr_data.get(k).setIsdefaultCurrency(true);
                } else {
                    arr_data.get(k).setIsdefaultCurrency(false);
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```